# Save a BufferedImage to BMP/PNG/JPG and then open it back

Tags: java, save, bufferedimage

I have made a project like Paint from windows and now I want to make the save/open buttons. I have found out how to save the bufferedImage, but the problem is how do I open it back in the correct location and be able to draw on it again?

Answer (score 2):

To read in an image, use [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

```
File myPath = new FIle("path to image");
BUfferedImage img = ImageIO.read(myPath);
```

Also what you could (should) do is load the image into your user space so that you don't edit the original image:

```
public static BufferedImage userSpace(BufferedImage image)
{
    BufferedImage newImage  = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    Graphics2D    graphics   = newImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    graphics.dispose(); 
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "user space"? A `BufferedImage` read into memory does not have any association with the original file on disk.